# What is the proper syntax to chain multiple queries together?

Tags: breeze, durandal, hottowel, q

I'm using the HotTowel SPA template which makes use of Durandal. In my Durandal ViewModels I am using Breeze to get some data from the database.

I have a datacontext class that I put all my breeze queries in and the queries all follow the pattern like the following:

```
getAthletes: function (queryCompleted) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Athletes");
            return manager
                .executeQuery(query)
                .then(queryCompleted)
                .fail(queryFailed)
        }
```

Since I'm doing an asynchronous call in the activate method of the view model, I have to return the promise that comes back from these calls in the activate method.

Using a single query works great like this:

```
function activate() {
  datacontext.getAthlete(loadAthlete);
}
```

However, if I need to perform two queries I run into problems, but only in the release version of my application. I have tried doing this with the following syntax:

```
function activate() {
  datacontext.getAthlete(loadAthlete).then(datacontext.getOtherData(loadOtherData));
}
```

This will work fine in debug mode, but when I deploy it out to the server and my scripts get bundled, I get an exception which isn't very clear.

> t is not a function

I've also tried chaining them together in my datacontext class like below, but I still get the same error.

```
getAthleteAndEfforts: function (athleteId, athleteQueryCompleted, effortsQueryCompleted) {
    var athleteQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Athletes").where("id", "==", athleteId);
    var effortsQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from("BestEfforts").where("athleteId", "==", athleteId);

    return manager.executeQuery(athleteQuery).then(athleteQueryCompleted)
        .then(manager.executeQuery(effortsQuery).then(effortsQueryCompleted))
        .fail(queryFailed);
}
```

So I'm assuming I just don't understand the Q.defer() enough to use it properly or there is something else going on.

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [RainerAtSpirit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965783/raineratspirit) for pointing me in the right direction to find this. I looked at John Papa's jumpstarter examples and he has a [datacontext that does this under the primeData function](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/blob/d55780927113308e016be15c9a2ef11fb5e92fcd/SPAJumpStart/App/services/datacontext.js).

So using the syntax he used there I was able to get it to work correctly like this:

```
getAthleteAndEfforts: function (athleteId, athleteQueryCompleted, effortsQueryCompleted) {
    return Q.all([
                datacontext.getAthlete(athleteId, athleteQueryCompleted),
                datacontext.getAthleteEfforts(athleteId, effortsQueryCompleted)]);
}
```

I had seen the Q.all in the [Q documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) but wasn't sure how to use it, but this example helped. I tested this and it works both in debug and release modes.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. As Breeze uses Q you've to do it the Q way, but the rule of thumb is the same. If your datacontext is async you need to return a promise.

Comment: Also as a note in your question you mentioned that the proper callbacks weren't being returned but when I look at the way you were calling them I believe you weren't doing what you intended - return manager.executeQuery(athleteQuery).then(athleteQueryCompleted) - the .then() method is to be completed once the query returns a callback, but you were passing the .then() method your observable (I assume, the name is funny) whereas I believe you probably want to call another method where the observable is populated with your results, provided the data is valid.  Just a note...

Comment: I ran out of room, but using .then() to call a method to check the data would be especially useful (for example) if you wanted to make a database call, check that the result is not null, and populate it with some arbitrary entity if it is null or something.

Comment: the athleteQueryCompleted was a function so it works fine in the "then" there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the first version is working at all, but you'd return a promise when datacontext is making async calls.

```
function activate() {
  return datacontext.getAthlete(loadAthlete);
}
```

or

```
function activate() {
  return datacontext.getAthlete(loadAthlete).then( return datacontext.getOtherData(loadOtherData));
}
```

Check @John Papa's jumpstarter for more examples: https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/search?q=activate

Comment: Hmmm.. That second example gives a syntax error. Looking through the samples now to see if I can find something similar.